# Searching a string using a list and returning multi-word variables.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, urllib

Code below.

Explanation of what I’m doing: I have a list of keywords. I need to identify if these keywords are present on any given web page (which I input). The issue I am running into is with keywords that are more than two words. For example, if you look at the results below, you will see that “Star” and “Wars” do not appear in the list. “Star Wars” is a phrase on my keywords list and I need the result to show as “Star Wars” as opposed to two separate items. Currently, I have the text from bs4 converting to a string then a list, which I know is incorrect because it separates based on the " " which, by default, will split the phrases I am searching for. Is there a way for me to search the string directly for phrases that exist on the imported list?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import pandas as pd

#Wikipedia Adress here
site= "website.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

#Company Website Here
site = "website.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

#Extracts text from soup and saves as souptext variable
gettext = soup.get_text()
gettext2 = soup2.get_text()
#converts to string
souptext = str(gettext)
souptext2 = str(gettext2)
#converts to list
split = souptext.split(' ')
split2 = souptext2.split(' ')

#combines both splits to one single list
combined = split + split2
#combines both strings to one string
combinedstr = souptext.lower() + souptext2.lower()

#Imports Excel File containing keywords
df = pd.read_csv('Movies.csv')

#Extracts desired column variables as keywords
mylist = df['Titles'].tolist()
liststr = str(mylist)

intersection = [i for i in mylist if i in combined]
results = list()
results.append(intersection)
print(results)

[['Avatar', 'Goodfellas', 'Saw', 'Crash', 'Gladiator', 'Scarface']]
```

Input was requested so here is an example of text from the webpage I would see (which is a string):

Movie fans have slowly been drifting away from nostalgic movies such as Star Wars and Star Trek. New generations prefer movies with modern special effects and CGI such as Avatar.

In this case, Star Wars and Star Trek would be keywords from mylist. However, they will not show in results because they are two-word variables.

Currently, I have the code set to split the html text string into a list. This works for single title movies but does not for movie titles that contain multiple words. that's the main issue I am trying to solve here. I know that splitting the string will not allow me to intersect titles with multiple words.

Comment: Please change your title to an explanation of your problem.

Comment: Some actual input would be nice to see.

Comment: Or at least show the type of `gettext` and explain why you do `str(gettext)`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve should be simple with regex.

```
import re
import requests

movie_list = ["batman","star wars", "star treck", "Blade Runner 2049"]
url = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls062017175/"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

movies_in_page = []
for movie in movie_list:
    if len(re.findall(r"\b{}\b".format(movie),html, flags=re.I|re.M) ) >0:
        movies_in_page.append(movie)
print()
print("{} Movies found in page: {}".format(len(movies_in_page),movies_in_page))
```

**Output**

```
>>> 3 Movies found in page: ['batman', 'star wars', 'Blade Runner 2049']
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way for me to search the string directly for phrases that exist on the imported list?

Yes, use the `in` operator.

```
>>> ' bar ' in 'foo bar baz'
True
```

You'll note that here I put spaces around the search term to prevent this sort of problem:

```
>>> 'bar' in 'the barren wasteland'
True
```

You'll still have issues with words at the beginning and end of the text.  You can add spaces onto your text to solve this, or you might start looking into regular expressions.

Comment: Searching for a regex is much more general and would actually work here.

Comment: How can I do this with a list though and then have it return the list of words that do match? So, to clarify, in your example, bar is a list and foo bar baz is a string.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agreed (which is why I mentioned it), but it's also a more complex solution and is not needed in all cases.  The simplest solution for the current problem is usually the best option.

Comment: @bdubs Write a loop that iterates through the list of search terms and keep track of which ones match.